# Push server implementation technology?

Tags: push-notification, server-push

I'm planning to develop a solution which uses push functionality. There will be a server and mobile device client application.

I need to know how to push messages in to the client from the server. That is my client application is passively waiting until a messages comes from the server.

What is the technology behind pushing the messages from the server.

Clients are in the form of  Android,J2me,BB,iphone etc

Comment: Is this a web app or an Iphone app or an Android app, etc.?

Comment: We'll Im thinking of different clients from Android,J2me,BB,iphone etc.

Comment: Probably worth checking out this [Real-Time Technologies Guide](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-technologies-guide) which covers things such as Comet, WebSockets and also provides a list of hosted services as well as solutions you can install yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google for "COMET", you'll get a lot of links. Generally speaking, you want a server framework that can park requests and pick them up when they have data to return. For example, a basic Java Servlet will keep a thread per request, and if you "park" a request (by doing some wait), the thread is suspended along with the request. In this way, you can only have as many clients waiting on a request as you can have threads in the server, which is not enough for big apps.

So, at the very least, you want a system where threads can be reused as requests are paused. As push is becoming popular again, frameworks to support it are blooming, so without more context it is hard to recommend a certain server/framework.

Having said that :-), in the Play Framework (http://www.playframework.org/) there is a sample chat application that uses three variations of "push". If anything, it's worth perusing the code (assuming that you know Java) to get a feel for the various solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at HTML5 web sockets. It's a way of opening a <del>raw TCP socket</del> socket that works like a TCP socket ([with some limitations](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/04/websockets-in-firefox/)) but is initiated over HTTP, from the browser, enabling true two-way communication. It's supported in many modern browsers, including the current iOS browser. Android doesn't support it, but there you can fall back on a Flash pixel. It's quite easy to write a Flash file that manages the socket and passes all the information back and forth to Javascript. If you're interested I think I might even have some code I could dig out for you.

Comment: WebSockets are not raw TCP sockets. WebSocket Flash fallback: https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js